# Unity Android launch camera after asking for permission

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-permissions

Consider the simplest camera app made in Unity for Android

```
// this script is attached to quad or plane
void Start()
    {
        WebCamTexture texture = new WebCamTexture();
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
        texture.Play();
    }
```

When I launch this it asks for permission for camera but does not launch the camera immediately after I grant it. I need to restart the app to actually launch the camera. Is there a way to launch the camera after granting permission?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission.html look at this doc

Comment: @NikolayGonza, thanks this is exactly what I need, but its not implemented in Unity 2018 yet which we have project in. Do you by any chance have an idea how to achieve it there?

Comment: you need to write your own plugin then, or use this with a coroutine, waintng needed permission, this was added from 2018.3 https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Android.Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission.html